# Watershed area unit in QGIS using GRASS

Tags: qgis

I have delineated a watershed using GRASS (QGIS 3.6), I got an area of 581659735,1237793. I do not know the unit of this watershed (m², km², Ha); it is confusing to me. How can I determine that?

Comment: What CRS are both your project and your data in?

Comment: We can't know the units of your data unless you tell us, though given that the Earth only has 149 million square kilometers of land area (and 510m km² of surface area), I can safely assert that it's not km².

Answer (score 2):

Processing tools, including the ones provided by GRASS, use the unit of the source layers CRS for calculations. If your source layer is in e.g. EPSG:4326, your result will be in degrees. If your source layer is projected in e.g. UTM, your result will be in meters.

Right click your layer and go to `Properties`. Navigate to `Information`. You will see an overview to your layer and also its units. If units are meters, your area will be in squaremeters.

[image]